# Is there a syntactically nice way to find and mutate an object in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am changing the contents of a note from an array of objects.

Example:

```
      const notes = [
         {text:'testText',title:'testTitle',uuid:'12'}, 
         {text:'testText',title:'testTitle',uuid:'21'}
      ]
```

And I want to change the second notes title and text based on the given uuid.

Currently this is my solution"

```
   let updatedNote = notes.find((note) => note.uuid === '21');
   updatedNote.text = text;
   updatedNote.title = title;
   updatedNote.tagList = tagList;
   updatedNote.tags = tags;
```

Is there a more clean and efficient way of doing this?
Thank you

Comment: "better" in what sense?

Comment: More clean looking basically. It feels like I am repeating updatedNote too many times to achieve this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which mutates the first argument by assigning the properties of each following argument to this target object ...

```js
const notes = [
  {text: 'testText', title: 'testTitle', uuid: '12'}, 
  {text: 'testText', title: 'testTitle', uuid: '21'},
];

const text = 'foo';
const title = 'bar';
const tagList = ['bazbiz', 'buzbaz'];
const tags = 'bazbiz,buzbaz';

Object.assign(

  // target object which will be mutated and also is the return value.
  notes.find((note) => note.uuid === '21'),

  // the source objects which properties will bee assigned to the target object.
  {
    text,
    title,
    tagList,
    tags,
  }

);

console.log('notes[1] :', notes[1]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you prefer :

```js
const updatedNote = {
    ...notes.find((note) => note.uuid === uuid),
    text, 
    title, 
    tagList, 
    tags,
};
```

It can be easily reduced if you don't put the new properties on new lines

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are creating a new variable to save the new Note values, if this is really necessary, other than just update, I suppose the find method is Ok and you can pass the values directly through an object (if you must update only this specific properties):

```
let updatedNote = notes.find((note) => note.uuid === uuid);

updatedNote = {text: "text", title:"title", tagList:"tagList", tags:"tags"}
```

Or even, if you want to update all properties from that object you can use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement:

```
let updatedNote = notes.find((note) => note.uuid === uuid);
let newProps = {text,title,tagList,tags}; //ES6+ Object Literal Declarations

for(let property in updateNote){
updateNote[property] = newProps[property];
}
```

Comment: I edited for more clarification. I don't really want to return any value. I just figured its better than doing notes.find((note) => note.uuid === uuid).text = 'stuff'; notes.find((note) => note.uuid === uuid).title = 'more stuff'